# VBA Pivot Table: Add Filter

Tags: vba, excel, filter, pivot

Using VBA code, I have created a Pivot table and then added row, columns and then the summation values. Now I need to add a filter on a column. 
Can you please let me know how can I add filters to this column.

Comment: Did you try some code? Can you post it? Did you do research on the topic? What did you search for? What did you find?

Comment: No I couldnt find any reference. Foe adding Row, Column and Summation I had used as below. But nothing for FILTER.

Comment: Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Order\ Amendment Approval Stage")
pvtFld.Orientation = xlRowField
pvtFld.Position = 5

Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("SOWPODateQtr")
pvtFld.Orientation = xlColumnField
pvtFld.Position = 1

Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("SERVICE ACV IN $ PLANNED")
pvtFld.Orientation = xlDataField
pvtFld.Position = 1
pvtFld.Function = xlSum
pvtFld.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

Comment: What exactly do you need a reference for? How to [apply filter to pivot table with VBA in Excel](https://www.google.at/search?q=Apply+filter+to+pivot+table+with+VBA+in+Excel&oq=Apply+filter+to+pivot+table+with+VBA+in+Excel&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.535j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: While creating a Pivot table manullay, we have the options to enter row fields, column fields, sum fields and then Filter fields. How do i replicate the 'Filter fields" options using VBA ?

Comment: A quick [search](https://www.google.at/search?safe=off&q=vba+excel+apply+filter+pivot+table&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHho_6rNjTAhXMORQKHUqRAuoQvwUIJCgA&biw=1536&bih=760) returns lots of useful examples you can try out. Try the code in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071662/filter-excel-pivot-table-using-vba) SO post and edit your question if you get stuck on a specific problem/line

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
Sub Makró2()
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Kimutatás1").PivotFields("a")
        .PivotItems("asd").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("hj").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Is it not easy as adding a row/Column syntax to a pivot. Somehting like this >

Comment: Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Account")
pvtFld.Orientation = xlRowField
pvtFld.Position = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of codes

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable Name").PivotFields("Column Name").Orientation = xlPageField.Position = 1
```